# Set up the DNS for any IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

How to get DNS address for a IP. Is it possible?

Please see the attached image:

[image]

Comment: Click on the question mark at the top of that window. The computer will present you with the help page which should explain what you need to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have your own DNS server then you can use 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 (google) or  208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220 (opendns) or some combination thereof.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the photograph, you're asking how to get the addresses of some valid DNS servers to put into your networking config.

If that's so, the first step is to ask your local network administrator.  Failing that, google are quite well-known to run a couple of free, public name servers on 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4; try those.  But not until you've asked your network admin what the right values are.